# LIMIT and unindexed column seem to prevent ORDER BY optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

What follows is my table. Some of the columns aren't necessary to reproduce, but this is my real-world, actual table, and it's small, so I post the whole thing:

```
CREATE TABLE `Alarms` (
  `AlarmId`        INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '32-bit ID',
  `Code`           BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `GenerationTime` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ExpiryTime`     TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ExpiryCause`    ENUM('natural','artificial') DEFAULT NULL,
  `AckTime`        TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `ClearTime`      TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`AlarmId`),
  KEY `AlarmExpiry` (`ExpiryTime`),
  KEY `AlarmLevels` (`AckTime`,`ClearTime`),
  KEY `AlarmTime`   (`GenerationTime`),
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Now, minimally, how to reproduce my problem.

---

The following uses the `AlarmTime` index for fast ordering and `LIMIT`ing:

```
SELECT
   `AlarmId`
FROM
   `Alarms`
ORDER BY
   `GenerationTime` DESC
 , `AlarmId` DESC
LIMIT
   2055820, 20
```

Explain:

```
id    select_type    table   type   possible_keys   key         key_len   ref      rows      Extra
1     SIMPLE         Alarms  index  (NULL)          AlarmTime   4         (NULL)   2050259   Using index
```

---

The following doesn't. It filesorts, slowly (a few seconds with ~2m rows):

```
SELECT
   `AlarmId`
 , `Code`
FROM
   `Alarms`
ORDER BY
   `GenerationTime` DESC
 , `AlarmId` DESC
LIMIT
   2055820, 20
```

Explain:

```
id    select_type    table   type   possible_keys   key         key_len   ref      rows      Extra
1     SIMPLE         Alarms  ALL    (NULL)          (NULL)      (NULL)    (NULL)   2050259   Using filesort
```

---

I don't understand why the `LIMIT` seemingly prevents me from being able to select any columns that don't form part of a key on the table.

The two seemingly relevant manual pages [1][2] don't appear to reference such a scenario.

What nuance of table indexes am I missing?

[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html
[2]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: The simple answer is that your first query doen't require reading the table itself, while the 2nd query does. If you have an index that includes both columns, it should be about as fast as the first query.

Comment: Using a high offset number in LIMIT is pretty much a no go. `LIMIT
   2055820, 20`  MySQL needs to fetch 2055840 rows and drop 2055820 rows again.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Then how are we supposed to implement paging?

Comment: @SloanThrasher: Hmm but the ORDER BY should still be index-driven, shouldn't it? This should not require a filesort surely. The more I use SQL the less I realise I know about how to make tables work properly! Ultimately I am going to need to pull out more than just those two columns.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition by using the autoincrement AlarmId   `WHERE AlarmId >= 2055820 LIMIT 20`  this is faster.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: The ordering is on GenerationTime,AlarmId not just AlarmId .. so your version is not equivalent. It'll break on wrap-around anyway.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition well you say so i dont know your data.

Comment: @RaymondNijland: Well it says so in the question

Comment: Re-read the limit-optimization link you provided. Basically, in your first query, it will never look at the table itself, while in the 2nd query, it will start with the index to find the first row, then it will have to read the table to complete it's work.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: I'm fine with it reading from the table; I'm not fine with it sorting the result via filesort. Plenty of other times I have sorted by a key and retrieved data from unindexed columns without penalty, unless I'm imagining things?

Comment: Can you post your EXPLAIN output.  I understand your question, "Why is it even doing a file sort since "Code" isn't even in the Order By statement"  But at the same time I'm with Sloan Thrasher, I believe the Read of "Code" from disk is whats causing the increase time, not necessarily the file sort.  as your assumption should be correct.. it isn't using "Code" in the file sort.

Comment: Fine with it or not, it works the way it works. A query that only uses columns in an index will almost always be faster, and one that uses columns outside the index will be slower, especially with large row sizes. Sometimes the "penalty" is small, and you may not have noticed it. But in this case, with a large number of rows in the table, and an order by that doesn't have a matching index, the penalty would be noticable.

Comment: @SloanThrasher: I realise that absolute passage of time will increase, but it shouldn't be dropping all use of indexes. Otherwise there's no point in having them.

Comment: @DarbyM: EXPLAIN's up

Comment: Ah, okay.. so when you add the column "Code" the optimizer no longer uses ANY index, because it believes it can do it faster without.  can you give this a try?   `ALTER TABLE alarms ADD INDEX GenerationTime_AlarmId (GenerationTime DESC, AlarmId DESC);`  This is both a compound index, as well as ordered in the same direction of your Order By.   It should opt to use the index in this case.  Please display the Explain with this index in place.

Comment: @DarbyM: The resulting explain is the same, with or without the `LIMIT`, unless I remove `Code` from the column list (as before). Even if I add `USE INDEX(\`GenerationTime_AlarmId\`)` wtf :(

Comment: I suppose at this juncture I should note that this is MariaDB 5.5.52 on CentOS 7 x86_64

Comment: Yeah, that would be a very good note...  While I haven't tested it yet.. but small optimization diffrences like this are the MAIN differences between DB's even from Version of MySQL to MySQL.   So I wouldn't be surprised if this is what you're running into.. I fully expect MySQL to have used the compound index in my given example.

Comment: @DarbyM: Yeah, me too - I've always been a little unclear on what having the Primary Key at the end of an index does, but I thought some variation of this would be effective, hence my question :(

Comment: Do you have a way to easily mock this up on MySQL 5.7 by chance?

Comment: @DarbyM: I was going to post a SQLFiddle originally but the site seems to be broken so I didn't. I'll work on an equivalent but I'm not quite sure how I'll generate all the data.

Comment: I have a DB up I use for nothing but testing these kinds of things.  If you can get me a CSV, I'll import it and tinker with it for a bit.  I'm currently board.

Comment: File Downloaded.  I added the below answer... as I did some testing with an empty table and was so far able to produce your results with zero data.   I'm confident I will see the same with data in field

Answer (score 2):

After doing some testing my MySQL server I can only confirm what Sloan Thrasher was saying...

The optimizer DOES in fact take into account the selected columns as well as the Order By columns.   Adding the following index Is whats needed.

```
ALTER TABLE alarms 
ADD INDEX GenerationTime_AlarmId_Code (GenerationTime DESC, AlarmId DESC, Code);
```

**Update:**

I have since confirmed with your data set as well... Creating the above combination index in DESC order, yields the best results. From 2.278 Sec Down to .765 Sec on my system.

As a side note, If `AlarmId DESC` is not needed in your Order By,

*(Eg. if you have 2 AlarmId with the exact same GenerationTime, you don't care which AlarmId shows in the list first)*

I don't see a reason to use it.  So I say remove it from Order by.  Makes is slightly faster yet.  ".749"

If on the other hand your NEED your AlarmId's to ALWAYS list in the same order, you will need to also Group By a deterministic Column (PK) to assure they show in the same order.    See [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html)

*If it is important to ensure the same row order with and without LIMIT, include additional columns in the ORDER BY clause to make the order deterministic.*

Comment: Yeah the `AlarmId` is in the sorting to guarantee a deterministic order, and adding every column I may wish to query to an index before I can use any index at all is not really feasible. :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

First, `LIMIT 2055820, 20` is *awful* and *unrealistic*.  Did someone sit there and press [Next] on a UI 102,791 times?!  I doubt it.  Do you really have a UI that extends that far?  Do you understand that the query *must* pass over 2,055,820 records before getting to the 20 that you want?

Sorry to be harsh, but I hate bad UI design.

As already mentioned, `INDEX(GenerationTime, AlarmId, Code)` is about the only thing that can be added to help the query.  And it would help both variants of your `SELECT`.  (Note: `DESC` is not necessary *in this case*.  The syntax is allowed in the `INDEX`, but it is ignored until version 8.0.)

If you *really* do need the pagination, see [*my article*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) on how to "remember where you left off".

If your UI is probing into a large dataset, then consider providing a way to pick (or enter) a value of `GenerationTime` as a starting point in this huge stream.

One thought is to break GenerationTime into about 50 equal ranges; let the user pick on; then provide him 50 subdivisions in there.  *Then* the scan is only about 50 pages of 20 rows each -- *much* more manageable.

Comment: _"Did someone sit there and press [Next] on a UI 102,791 times?!"_ No, of course not; they jumped to the end: `[|<][<][1][2][3]...[102,789][102,790][102,791][>][>|]` I really don't see what's so "unrealistic" about having a lot of data and wanting to let people seek around in it and consuming it. This is literally what a database is for. I concede that there may be flashier ways to present this data, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: _"Do you understand that the query must pass over 2,055,820 records before getting to the 20 that you want?"_ No, I don't understand that. Pointer addition is a very quick operation.

Comment: _"Sorry to be harsh, but I hate bad UI design."_ Sorry to be harsh, but I hate unfounded assumptions (with no domain knowledge whatsoever) translated into criticisms off the bat.

Comment: _"Then the scan is only about 50 pages of 20 rows each -- much more manageable."_ You're making assumptions. Many rows could be generated in a very small space of time; that's a fact of the network in question. And entries of more than a certain age are routinely purged anyway. I don't see how your suggestion can work with such a potentially uneven distribution.

Comment: _"If you really do need the pagination"_ On a tangent, I really hate the recent trend of doing away with pagination and replacing it with an endless auto-loading stream, that you have to sit there scrolling through from the top every time you want to find something. Twitter and Facebook started it and it's infuriating!

Comment: I'll read your link in the morning - it may have what I need. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: "Pointer addition" does not happen.  BTree structures are too complex for that optimization.

Comment: I'm not too excited about infinite scroll, either.  I strongly suspect it puts a potentially bad burden on the user's browser, which then chews up lots of his RAM.

Comment: Indeed - FB is particularly bad at this as it doesn't unload the scrolled-past stuff. If you're trying to get at old photos in a large album (say, Mobile Uploads), good luck! Meh.

Comment: I now have two layers of paging - the user first selects a date (having been presented with a list of dates, and a reasonable amount of information about how much happened on each date), then they can page through the events found on that date. There could still be a lot of pages on a particular date, but generally there will be _far_ less than there would have been pages overall. So although I am still disappointed that MySQL isn't better at `LIMIT` over an index-sorted dataset when it needs to read data from the table itself, it doesn't really matter for me any more. :)

Comment: As such, with the assumptions removed and a note added about this `LIMIT` behaviour (I still don't understand why it can't apply the offset in index space _then_ pull out the 20 rows it needs from the table) this answer can probably be accepted now

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - What version of MySQL are you using?  I think newer versions have learned to do the "lazy load" that you describe -- scan the _index_ to do the `OFFSET`, then reach into the _data_ for the `SELECT` stuff.  (This would only apply if the `WHERE` + `GROUP` + `ORDER` are handled completed by the index.)  An "index range scan" is usually faster than a "table range scan", but it is not fast enough to make `OFFSET 2055820` painless.  What is the `EXPLAIN` for the recommended 3-col index?

Comment: MariaDB 5.5.56 (CentOS 7), and whatever they bundle on CentOS 6 too. I don't have the data & query to hand any more to do an `EXPLAIN` (I was on an old-question "cleanup" yesterday, posting ancient results!) but will see if I can whip something up. Will be interesting to see whether this version is at least "lazy" when all the data is in the index; indeed, my original results (per the question) suggest so. If it doesn't even do this, that really does seem like a silly limitation (no pun intended) but glad to hear it may have been improved in versions since.